# How to autofill a form on a web page when a link is clicked by php?

Tags: php

I want to write a program that when a user click on a link, it will open the modem page (with specific ip address). In the login page I want to automatically fill the login form with default values and press Submit button automatically, so the user doesn't need to enter the Username and password. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Where are you stuck with this exactly? What have you tried so far? You need to be far more specific about the problem before we can suggest anything meaningful. Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial service, free write-my-code provider, or a discussion forum or anything like that.

Comment: `I want to automatically fill the login form with default values`...generally you can get your browser to remember credentials for you so you don't have to type them in.

Comment: P.S. Anything you want to automate within a browser is almost certainly going to involve JavaScript, not PHP, since that's a server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

If the form you are trying to fill out has a CSRF(Cross site request forgery) then you will not be able to achieve this, however if it's not protected from CSRF, then you can simple submit a POST request to that URL. First, you need to gather some data.

1. Get the action destination from the login form using inspect element (sometimes you won't find an obvious  tag, then find the action triggered by clicking the login button)
2. Gather the field names being sent to that controller (input name='{name_here}')
3. Create an HTML page that contains an html form that points to the same controller, with the same fields, populated by your PHP variables
4. Submit the form using javascript

Here's an example of me sending a "username" and "Password" to "form.cgi" which is the destination of my modems login form

```
<form action="192.168.100.1/form.cgi" method="post" hidden>
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually there is no form, just input fields that is handled by javascript. I tried to open the .js files from page source but it is locked and can't be loaded.

Comment: you can use chrome's debugger to unminify and make it more readable. try to read the javascript and figure out the destination & fields and this would still apply